# A simple question on representation on $p$-adic groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-adic group (for example classical groups) and $\pi$ is a smooth finite length representation of $G$.

Let $U$ be a unipotent subgroup of $G$ and $\psi$ is a non-trivial character of $U$.

Suppose that $\operatorname{Hom}_{U}(\pi,\psi) \ne 0$.

Then it is written in some literature that there is a unique irreducible constituent $\sigma$ of $\pi$ such that $\operatorname{Hom}_{U}(\sigma,\psi) \ne 0$.

I don't know why this holds. Could anyone explain this?

Comment: I think it uses some multiplicity one property of Whittaker model.

Comment: This is trivially false. E.g. take $\pi =\sigma \oplus \sigma$. This is may be true when $\pi$ is parabolically induced from an irreducible supercuspidal representation, under some assumptions.

Comment: @PaulBroussous, oh I am sorry. I missed one  condition on $\pi$ such that $\pi$ has a unique irreducible quotient. With this condition, can we deduce the claim?

Comment: Is $U$ any unipotent subgroup or is it the unipotent radical of a Borel subgroup? Is $\psi$ assumed to be generic? Which literature did you find this in?

Comment: @KentaSuzuki, Yes! $U$ is the unipotent radical of a Borel subgroup and $\psi$ is a generic character of $U$. The literature I mentioned is Gan--Savin's paper "https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/representations-of-metaplectic-groups-i-epsilon-dichotomy-and-local-langlands-correspondence/EB78E272B49563E482112C2F5C0BB8E4". Corollary 9.3 (ii).